# Pandas Dataframes: Forward Fill Multiple Rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, fillna

```
input = pd.DataFrame({
    'Timestamp': [
        pd.Timestamp('19/01/2022  10:00:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('19/01/2022  10:00:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('19/01/2022  15:00:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('19/01/2022  15:30:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('19/01/2022  16:00:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('19/01/2022  19:30:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('19/01/2022  20:00:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('19/01/2022  20:30:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('20/01/2022  13:00:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('20/01/2022  13:30:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('20/01/2022  14:00:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('20/01/2022  14:50:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('20/01/2022  15:00:00')],
    'Name': [
        'A', 'B', np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN,
        'C', np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN,
        'D', np.NaN]})
```

I am trying to forward fill multiple rows at once between timestamps but I have not found a quick way to do it. Could you please share your solution?

Each row corresponds to a name entry at a given timestamp. There can be multiple names for the same timestamp. I want to propagate this group of names until the next non-nan value.

I have tried a simple for loop but this is relatively slow (the array will have about 100,000 rows).

Desired output is:

```
desired_output = pd.DataFrame({
    'Timestamp': [
        pd.Timestamp('19/01/2022  10:00:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('19/01/2022  10:00:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('19/01/2022  15:00:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('19/01/2022  15:00:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('19/01/2022  15:30:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('19/01/2022  15:30:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('19/01/2022  16:00:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('19/01/2022  16:00:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('19/01/2022  19:30:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('19/01/2022  20:00:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('19/01/2022  20:30:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('20/01/2022  13:00:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('20/01/2022  13:30:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('20/01/2022  14:00:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('20/01/2022  14:50:00'),
        pd.Timestamp('20/01/2022  15:00:00')],
    'Name': [
        'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B',
        'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C',
        'D', 'D']})
```

Please find my attempt below:

```
import time

t0 = time.time()

unique_timestamps = input.Timestamp.unique()
new_entries = []
last_valid = None
for ut in unique_timestamps:
    val = input[input.Timestamp == ut]['Name'].values
    if type(val[0])==float and np.isnan(val[0]) and last_valid is not None:
        new_entries.append(pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': ut, 
                                         'Name': last_valid}))
    else:
        last_valid = input[input.Timestamp == ut]['Name']
output = pd.concat([input, pd.concat(new_entries)]).dropna().sort_values('Timestamp')

t1 = time.time()
print(str(t1-t0) + 's')
```

Comment: Post the data as text instead of [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). "Could you please share your solution?" - you need to show some effort, see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Suraj - I have added a block of code for the dataframe that I am trying to fit

Comment: Thank you - the problem is that the ffill method only propagates the latest value. For instance, I would need both A and B to be propagated from 19/01/2022  10:00:00 to 19/01/2022  16:00:00 timestamps. ffill method will only propagate B value

Comment: Show us your code please. I found two ways to do this but they have fundamental differences, so I'd rather post whatever is closest to your code.

Comment: @wjandrea I have posted my attempt above but it will be too slow for a dataframe with thousands of rows

Comment: quick note:  `input` is a keyword in python. So use a different name for that variable...

Comment: @D.L It's a builtin, not a keyword;  [keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) can't be assigned to. That said, yeah, it's best to avoid [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) it.

Comment: @wjandrea.  thanks for correcting my nomenclature...

Answer (score 0):

You can groupby `Timestamp` and [agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) `Name` into a collection, then [ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) and [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html).

I'm not sure how to do this most efficiently, but the simplest way I've found to write it is like this:

```
(
    df
    .groupby('Timestamp')
    .agg({'Name': lambda s: s if pd.notna(s.iat[0]) else None})
    .ffill()
    .explode('Name')
    )
```

This follows your logic on how to detect NaNs, i.e. `pd.notna(s.iat[0])` takes the place of `np.isnan(val[0])`. There are possibly simpler ways to do it, but I'm not sure if they would work, e.g. even `lambda s: s`, which I'm surprised works the way it does (single elements become scalars while multiple elements become arrays).

Result:

```
                    Name
Timestamp               
2022-01-19 10:00:00    A
2022-01-19 10:00:00    B
2022-01-19 15:00:00    A
2022-01-19 15:00:00    B
2022-01-19 15:30:00    A
2022-01-19 15:30:00    B
2022-01-19 16:00:00    A
2022-01-19 16:00:00    B
2022-01-19 19:30:00    C
2022-01-19 20:00:00    C
2022-01-19 20:30:00    C
2022-01-20 13:00:00    C
2022-01-20 13:30:00    C
2022-01-20 14:00:00    C
2022-01-20 14:50:00    D
2022-01-20 15:00:00    D
```

Comment: thank you so much! That is more elegant than my original solution and three time faster. This 'explode' function is very handy.

Comment: It would be great to also this your solution using merge. I have tried to upvote but apparently I need 15 reputation to cast a vote (but my feedbcak has been recorded)

Answer (score 0):

### Merge

You could [de-duplicate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) the key column (`Timestamp`), then [ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) it [according to](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) the values (`Name`), then [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging) with the original, which takes care of the multiple values. Here I'm assigning a separate column with the ffill, to only be used as a merge key.

```
(
    df[['Timestamp']].drop_duplicates()
    .assign(_ts_merge=lambda d: d.where(df['Name'].notna()).ffill())
    .merge(df.set_index('Timestamp'), left_on='_ts_merge', right_index=True)
    .drop(columns='_ts_merge')
)
```

```
             Timestamp Name
0  2022-01-19 10:00:00    A
0  2022-01-19 10:00:00    B
2  2022-01-19 15:00:00    A
2  2022-01-19 15:00:00    B
3  2022-01-19 15:30:00    A
3  2022-01-19 15:30:00    B
4  2022-01-19 16:00:00    A
4  2022-01-19 16:00:00    B
5  2022-01-19 19:30:00    C
6  2022-01-19 20:00:00    C
7  2022-01-19 20:30:00    C
8  2022-01-20 13:00:00    C
9  2022-01-20 13:30:00    C
10 2022-01-20 14:00:00    C
11 2022-01-20 14:50:00    D
12 2022-01-20 15:00:00    D
```

This works a bit differently from your code with how it handles NaNs, but I'm not sure if there's any practical difference.